# Custom Css is Not Working on Live Site in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, customization

When I trying write `CSS` code for button or menu effect in `style.css` file then its not giving any effect on live website of `Wordpress`.

It works in locally vary well and also when I made changes in page source(Inspect Element).

So What can I do?

Answer (score 5):

Please follow the steps:

**Step 1**

[image: Step 1]

Launch the WordPress Customizer interface by going to Appearance → Customize in your WordPress dashboard

**Step 2**
[image: Step 2]

Then, click on the option for Additional CSS in the WordPress Customizer sidebar (it should be at the bottom):

**Step 3**
[image: Step 4]

Now! You can write your CSS code

Answer (score 0):

If your Style.CSS is not updating. Then you can Navigate in Admin Panel - Appearance - Customize - Additional CSS
In Additional CSS you can write your CSS code instead of writing in Style.css file.
Also write  `!important` if necessary
Eg. 

`.classname {
   display:none!important;
}`